# SwiftUI - How to implement "hide when scrolling" action to Search Bar (Xcode 12.1 - iOS 14)

Tags: ios, scroll, swiftui, hide, searchbar

I tried looking for an answer to this problem, but all of the solutions I found either were with UIKit, or needed me to add something to the AppDelegate/SceneDelegate. Since I'm using SwiftUI and Xcode 12.1 (that doesn't have AppDelegate and SceneDelegate anymore), I'm here asking this question:

How can I make this SearchBar disappear when user scrolls down (and leave it hidden until he/she scrolls down)?

Right now it works fine (even though I don't really like the animation of the cancel Button), and [it look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHaNS.jpg).
I have Search.swift like this:

```
import SwiftUI
 
struct Search: View {
@Binding var text: String

@State private var isEditing = false

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        TextField("Search ...", text: $text)
            .padding(7)
            .padding(.horizontal, 25)
            .background(Color(.systemGray6))
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .overlay(
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .padding(.leading, 8)
             
                    if isEditing {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.text = ""
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "multiply.circle.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                .padding(.trailing, 8)
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.isEditing = true
            }

        if isEditing {
            Button(action: {
                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                self.isEditing = false
                self.text = ""

            }) {
                Text("Cancel")
            }
            .padding(.trailing, 10)
            .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
            .animation(.default)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Then in my Content View I have this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var dm : DataManager
    @State var searchText = ""
    @State private var isEditing = false        
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Search(text: $searchText)
                     .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                Form {
                    ForEach(dm.storageValues.filter({ searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.valueName.contains(searchText) })) { data in
                        Text(data.valueName)
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Example")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if they can be useful, but the DataManager is like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class DataManager : Equatable, Identifiable, ObservableObject {


static let shared = DataManager()

@Published var storageValues : [ValueModel] = []
typealias StorageValues = [ValueModel]

//The rest of the code
}
```

With the ValueModel that is like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ValueModel : Codable, Identifiable, Equatable, ObservableObject, Comparable {

    var id = UUID()
    var valueName : String
    var notes : String?
    var expires : Date?
    
    init(valueName: String, notes: String?, expires: Date?) {
        self.valueName = valueName
        self.notes = notes
        self.expires = expires
    }
}
```

For the SearchBar I followed [this guide](https://www.appcoda.com/swiftui-search-bar/)

Thanks to everyone who will help me!

Comment: If you want SearchBar be on top only why don't you just add it as first view in scrolling view (Form in this case)?

Comment: Could you write a code example?